# how to show only some columns for specific role name in order view?

Tags: sales

we have customers that order and ship the products and they can see their orders but in this page prices and tax are shown and we don't want to show them
the code is in `sales/order/view/items.phtml`

I will get my role name and then I can write if the role then not show:

```
$admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();
    $role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
    $role_name = $role_data['role_name'];
```

Items.phtml:

```
<?php $_items = $this->getItemsCollection() ?>
    <?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item):?>
        <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++;?>
        <tbody class="<?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
            <?php 
            //if($role_name!="Europe")   
            echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php
            //if($role_name!="Europe")   
            echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
```

for example I want to show **Item Status** but not others like **Original Price
Price,Qty   Subtotal** and etc 
I don't know how to write my condition here to make it possible

I know that getItemHtml is comming from abstract.php and is

```
public function getItemHtml(Varien_Object $item)
{
    if ($item->getOrderItem()) {
        $type = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductType();
    } else {
        $type = $item->getProductType();
    }

    return $this->getItemRenderer($type)
        ->setItem($item)
        ->setCanEditQty($this->canEditQty())
        ->toHtml();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`

I wrote my condition there and now I have two different level access for showing the elements of the order table.